# I'm trying to make an Alert box with two different colors. Ex. Image included

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get an alert box working when someone opens this page but I'm having some trouble. I'll show you what I mean by that.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

[image]

**What I got so far:**

[image]

So as you can see I cannot get the text and the close button on the blue layer of the box. Any solution to this?

Also I tried making it a bit smaller. It's all over the page and I did try changing the padding but nothing worked.  Here's my code, I only included HTML and CSS since I didn't use any JS yet.

```css
.alert {
  padding: 40px 30px;
  background-color: #c0bcbc;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 45px solid dodgerblue;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
    <strong>NOTICE!</strong> An update is available.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO! Here's a freebie to get you started, have a great weekend!

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.modal {
  width: 35%;
  min-width: 20rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: #333 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom: black 2px solid;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 110%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.modal-header .close {
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .25s ease;
}

.modal-header .close:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.modal-content {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-footer button {
  margin: 1rem;
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 110%;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" role="alert">

  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">    
      Header
      <button type="button" class="close">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      Words Words Words
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button">Do Stuff</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your blue area is a border, where you can't put content.

Hope you find useful thoughts from my snippet.

```css
.alert {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 350px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}

.modal-header {
  background-color: #3073bb;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

.modal-body {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 10px 40px 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
  min-height: 90px;
}

.btn-ok {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3073bb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <span><strong>NOTICE!</strong> An update is available.</span>
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="message">Alert this pages</div>
     <button class="btn-ok">OK</button>
   </div>
</div>
```